# Eclipse, Java - Exlude Folder from all Validation

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to exclude a folder from all validation in Eclipse. I got some generated folders (generated with npm for the grunt build) in my project and there are some files in there which have errors. Eclipse takes very long to validate these folders and even throws an eclipse exception (stackoverflow while validating).
The maven build works perfectly.

So I would like to excluse the whole folder and all subfolders from the validation. The only thing I found is preferences --> validation but there I can only exclude the folder from each validator (e.g. XSL,XML,Web, ...).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try for files which you might like to have in your Eclipse project, but might not want them to be built.

To do this, right-click on the file in the Project Explorer, choose Resource Configurations > Exclude from Build and choose the configurations that you want.

To completely exclude the file, choose all the available configurations.

[image]

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for but i works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If errors are all javascript errors you can exclude the generated folders from project properties->Javascript -> Include Path-> Source Tab

add some regular expressions or just ** for exclude all.

Comment: Thanks but sadly the errors are HTML Problems, Web Resource Problems and other problems.